# Looking through column C from 3 to bottom? Excel

Tags: excel

Here is my formula, it works perfectly except it looks from the top of C to the bottom of C. I want it to look through C3 to the end of C. Is this possible?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Jobs List'!$C:$C,MATCH(ROWS(AG$12:AG12),'Jobs List'!$R:$R,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(K$8:K$11,MATCH(ROWS(C$7:C7),$M$8:$M$11,0)),""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original formula, you might replace `$C:$C` with something like `OFFSET($C$3,0,0,ROWS($C:$C)-ROW($C$3)+1)`.

Or, in Excel 2007 or 2010, you might consider using a data table with structured references.  So, if your data table is named Your_Table and column C is labeled "Your Column", you could just use `Your_Table[Your Column]` to refer to the "used" part of column C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hard code the values.

`C3:C65536` for Excel 2003 and earlier

`C3:C1048576` for Excel 2007 and 2010

Comment: Is this the only way? I hate to ask only because I was hoping for something like C3:C  but I know I was hoping for too much.

Comment: I tried `C3:C` and was getting an error. I think this is going to be the only way to accomplish it.